# Using credentials for ansible-galaxy with private gitlab repo in a Jenkins Job

Tags: git, jenkins, credentials, ansible-galaxy

I have a set of roles that I need to install with ansible-galaxy.

```
- src: 'https://gitlab.private/role-openstack-net.git'
  scm: 'git'
  version: '1.0.0'
  name: 'role-openstack-net'

- src: 'https://gitlab.private/role-openstack-subnet.git'
  scm: 'git'
  version: '1.0.0'
  name: 'role-openstack-subnet'
```

In real case, I have about 20 roles.

All the roles are private, so when I run:

```
ansible-galaxy install -f -c -r galaxy.yml
```

it asks me for the user / pass for each role, which is kind of bothering

Manually, I do:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

I enter my credentials once, and then it remembers it for all

But how should I do in a Jenkins Job ?

I saw here there is a way of putting a token:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/34621

but it doesn't seem to be work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is currently no support for passing credential parameters into ansible-galaxy at run time.

It is possible to add the credentials into the `requirements.yml`, but generally adding credentials into code is not ideal due to the ease that others could one day exploit them.

The solution is to update `requirements.yml` at run time.

Create a Gitlab Personal Access Token by viewing your profile and updating the settings:
[https://private.gitlab/profile/personal_access_tokens](https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens)

Use the secrets manager of your choice to set the variable PAT_TOKEN with the token at run time.

In your Jenkins script use `sed` to update `requirements.yml` before `ansible-galaxy install`

```
sed -i "s#https://gitlab.private/#https://oauth2:${PAT_TOKEN}@gitlab.private/#g" requirements.yml
```

If you were using Gitlab-ci instead of Jenkins, it is possible to use the existing ci token:

```
sed -i "s#https://gitlab.private/#https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.private/#g" requirements.yml
```

Comment: will this work for GitHub too?

Answer (score 0):

In case of you have git installed,
you can use this for gitlab:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
echo "https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@$mygitlab.com" >>  ~/.git-credentials
chmod 600 ~/.git-credentials
```

CI_JOB_TOKEN is the token which the runner use to pull the code.
You can use your own one (less secure)